# How change String to Date format

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I have this string: 2018-09-22 10:17:24.772000
I want to convert it to Date:

```
 SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");

    String sdate = "2018-09-22 10:17:24.772000";
    Date dateFrom = simpleDateFormat.parse(sdate);
```

but it shows: Sat Sep 22 10:17:24 GMT+03:30 2018

Comment: Could you please show your expected output?

Comment: can you tell me date output you want

Comment: I believe you should try `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ`, to prevent default timezone applying.

Comment: @StasLelyuk your format in logcat : Unparseable date

Comment: Oops, it should be "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Comment: It looks to me like the expected output (if your JVM is set to time zone GMT+03:30). I do recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class, though. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Let me guess, you’re coding for Android? The Android `SimpleDateFormat` behaves a little different from the one in standard Java (just to make already confusing matters even more confusing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you should do instead, you are printing date object itself, you should print its format.

I will provide the code with old date api and new local date api :

```
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");

    String sdate = "2018-09-22 10:17:24.772000";
    Date dateFrom = simpleDateFormat.parse(sdate);

    System.out.println(dateFrom); // this is what you do
    System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(dateFrom)); // this is what you should do

    // below is from new java.time package

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(sdate, formatter).format(formatter));
```

output is :

```
Sat Sep 22 10:30:16 EET 2018
2018-09-22 10:30:16.000000

2018-09-22 10:17:24.772000
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have converted it to a Date. What is your desired result? I suspect what you are wanting to do is to create another Simple date format that shows your expected format and then use `simpledateformat2.format(dateFrom)`

I should also point out based on past experience that you should add a Locale to your simple date formats otherwise a device with a different language setting may not be able to execute this code

`SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS", Locale.US);`

Answer (score 0):

**Hope This will help you**

```
public class Utils {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String mytime="2018-09-22 10:17:24.772000";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");

        Date myDate = null;
        try {
            myDate = dateFormat.parse(mytime);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String finalDate = timeFormat.format(myDate);

        System.out.println(finalDate);
    }
}
```